# How to get enum labels in chartkick piechart instead of integer value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, enums, chartkick

Gender is defined as:

`enum gender: {male: 1, female: 2, other: 3}`

chartkick is used to represent gender data in a piechart

`pie_chart @registrations.group(:gender).count`

How can I get Labels for the pie chart as Male/Female and not integer values 1/2 etc..?

Comment: `@registrations.first.gender.humanize` what this gives?

Comment: It gives the output as 'Male' or 'Female' but so does if humanize is not used  as - @registrations.first.gender

Answer (score 3):

My solution having had the same problem, hopefully useful for other folks:

```
<%= pie_chart @registrations.group(:gender).count.map {|k,v| [User.genders.key(k), v] }.to_h %>
```

Supposing gender is a enum value of User.

Comment: Would like to add that `Model_A.group(:object_id).sum(:attribute).map { |k,v| [(@exercise.filter { |ex| ex.id == k }).pluck(:name).join(','), v] }.to_h` where `@exercise = Model_B.all` also works.  I had one table that was storing the ids of another table and this allowed me to pull the ids names and display them instead of the id.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller you send an array with the label and the value

```
@registration_genders = [['male', Registration.where(gender: 1).size], ['female', Registration.where(gender: 2).size]]
```

Then to represent the data on the pie chart you could use

```
<%= pie_chart @registration_genders %>
```